# What are all of Harry Dresden's foci?

Tags: magic, the-dresden-files, jim-butcher

In [*The Dresden Files*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Dresden_Files), [Harry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harry_Dresden) is pretty well known for his staff and blasting rod, but those aren't the only foci he's used.  What other foci has Harry used pre [*Ghost Story*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ghost_Story_%28Butcher_novel%29)?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

All the ones that I can recall --

- Staff
- Blasting Rod
- Shield bracelet
- Force Rings (though I don't recall hearing about them in awhile)
- Pentacle amulet

Answer (score 8):

Ones that I remember:

- Rune Sword
- Silver Bear Belt Buckle (or something like that)

Comment: I don't remember either of those.

Comment: And, re-reading the series, I do.  The 'Rune Sword' is his cane sword, and it helps him with Earth Magic, and the belt buckle was only used once, but worked perfectly...until he overextended and almost died.

Comment: Bear Belt Buckle mentioned in Blood Rites

Comment: @ltfishie I don't recall it being mentioned in Blood Rites. The only instance I know of was in Fool Moon either just prior or just after (can't recall exact order) jumping out of a moving vehicle to take on the Streetwolves. I don't remember it ever being mentioned again.

Comment: @rcollyer In _Fool Moon,_ Harry uses a super-energy-drink potion to survive the conflict with the Streetwolves. The bear belt buckle is a focus that does essentially the same thing, which he uses to carry himself through key events in _Blood Rites_ before burning it out.

Answer (score 5):

I think the model of Chicago and the inlaid circle in Harry's basement count as foci as well.

Comment: I wouldn't think the circle is a focus, it's just a convenience.

Answer (score 3):

The main other one is his shield bracelet.

Comment: oh yes, i forgot about the shield bracelet.